# trouble in eclipce with tomcat

Tags: windows-10, java, eclipse, tomcat, wamp

i want to start tomcat server in eclipse and I got this message:

[image]

I got this error message in the console

```
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.96
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server built:          Jul 24 2019 13:00:10 UTC
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server number:         7.0.96.0
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Name:               Windows 10
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Version:            10.0
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Architecture:          amd64
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Version:           1.8.0_202-b08
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\IT\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.96
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\IT\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.96
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\IT\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.96\endorsed
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_202/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\IT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\IT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools\WinNT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin;C:\Users\IT\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\IT\Desktop;;.
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 1212 ms
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service Catalina
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.96
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:33 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
AVERTISSEMENT: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [284] milliseconds.
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ProjetFormation2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ProjetFormation2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: <url-pattern> RegisterServlet invalide dans l'association de servlet (servlet mapping)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3486)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1452)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1300)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5606)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

sept. 22, 2019 7:55:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:711)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ProjetFormation2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ProjetFormation2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: <url-pattern> RegisterServlet invalide dans l'association de servlet (servlet mapping)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3486)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1452)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1300)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5606)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

sept. 22, 2019 7:55:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:711)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ProjetFormation2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ProjetFormation2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: <url-pattern> RegisterServlet invalide dans l'association de servlet (servlet mapping)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3511)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3486)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1452)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1300)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5606)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

sept. 22, 2019 7:55:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFOS: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFOS: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFOS: Arrêt du service Catalina
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFOS: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
sept. 22, 2019 7:55:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFOS: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

I'm running under windows 10 with wamp server

Comment: There's an error somewhere in an `<url-pattern>` in your `web.xml`. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1485155/edit) your question and share the `web.xml`.

Comment: hi you mean in the project i kow it but even if i saray the tomact without the projet the error msg  remains the same